# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison error python?

Tags: python

im trying to use mergesort to sort lists of numbers, and compare how the time taken to sort lists of varying lengths differ between sorting methods (bubble, selection etc). So i use the following code to test this:

```
k=0
times=[]

while k<n:
    x=list(range(1,2**k))
    shuffle(x)
    start=clock()
    selectionsort(x)
    end=clock()
    times.append(end-start)
    k=k+1
return(times)
```

where shuffle is my code for shuffle sorting, this would change to mergesort and selection sort. When I test the shuffle sort and the selection sort the code runs as required, however when I test the mergesort I get a maximum recursive depth exceeded in comparison error. my code for the mergesort is as follows:

```
def mergesort(list):
    if len(list) == 1:
        return list

    m = len(list)//2
    l = mergesort(list[:m])
    r = mergesort(list[m:])

    if len(l)<1 or len(r)<1:
        return l or r

    result = []
    i = j = 0
    while (len(result)<len(r)+len(l)):
        if l[i] < r[j]:
            result.append(l[i])
            i = i+1
        else:
            result.append(r[j])
            j = j+1
        if i == len(l) or j == len(r):
            result.extend(l[i:] or r[j:])
            break
    return result
```

can anyone suggest why i might be getting this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend you to read how the merge-sort works. It's build up from two different functions - one, to split lists into two others, and the second one to merge them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of your error, and also your actual input to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mergesort` function doesn't work correctly if the argument it is passed is an empty list. It will recurse forever, because your base case only stops it when the length is exactly `1`.

Since your driver code runs the sort code on `list(range(1,2**k))` and `k` is initially zero, you get an empty list on the first iteration (`range(1, 1)` is empty).

To fix this issue, change the base case of your sort to stop if the list is empty (since there's nothing to sort):

```
def mergesort(list):
    if len(list) <= 1: # less than or equal!
        return list
```

One further suggestion (unrelated to your issue): It's a very bad idea to use `list` as a variable name. When you do, you mask the builtin `list` type, which can lead to confusing bugs. A common alternative is `lst` (but you can use a more descriptive name if you want).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm relatively new to coding so any tips are appreciated!